# How to generate one aggregate report in a multi-module project and non-aggregate reports for each child project with the MojoHaus Taglist Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I am unable to create one Apache Maven site containing multiple reports generated by the [MojoHaus Taglist Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin). It seems that one either has to decide on an aggregate report or on an non-aggregate report. But I would like to have both in the site output:

- aggregate report: Generated one for the Aggregator POM (multi-module). This should not be inherited, i.e. there should only be one report, even if additional Aggregator POMs are involved.
- non-aggregate report: Generated for each Child POM.

I have the following declared in my Aggregator POM `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <configuration>
                <!--
                TODO(2023-06-16 by wolters): It does not seem possible to create aggregate reports for a parent
                but non-aggregate reports for a child with the MojoHaus Taglist Plugin..
                -->
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

After running `mvn site-deploy` the created site contains an aggregated report for the multi-module project, but no report for the child project.

1. Is it possible to achieve the creation of both reports with the MojoHaus Taglist Plugin?
2. If it is possible: Can you provide a solution without using Maven profiles?

I tried different approaches, e.g. adding the plugin to the `<builds><plugin>` section and specifying an `<execution>`. But so far I wasn't able to achieve the desired result.

I am using the following:

- Apache Maven v3.9.2
- MojoHaus Taglist Maven Plugin v3.0.0

Comment: Try to create a maven [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), with the build section in it. One profile for aggregated reports and one without. Keep in mind, that the configuration you add to the `pluginManagement` section is inherited to all other declarations and need to be removed.

Comment: @luckyluke Thanks for your comment. I don't want to use Maven profiles (should have added that to the question). Your hint regarding the inheritance of the `pluginManagement` section guided me into the right direction: I've explicitly added a `reportSet` with the report `taglist` for the plugin. By adding the `aggregate` option to the `configuration` of that `reportSet`, I was able to include both reports in the Maven site. I may add an extensive answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the user "luckyluke" that guided me into the right direction. Here is the anwer to my question.

---

I was able to create both an aggregate report (in the Aggregator POM) **and** a non-aggregate report for each leaf/child POM with the "MojoHaus Taglist Maven Plugin".

1. Configure the plugin in the `<build>/<pluginManagement>` section of the Parent POM `pom.xml`.

   ```
   <build>
       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.0.0</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <emptyComments>true</emptyComments>
                       <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
                       <multipleLineComments>true</multipleLineComments>
                       <showEmptyDetails>true</showEmptyDetails>
                       <skipTestSources>false</skipTestSources>
                       <tagListOptions>
                           <tagClasses>
                               <tagClass>
                                   <displayName>To-do Tags</displayName>
                                   <tags>
                                       <tag>
                                           <matchString>TODO</matchString>
                                           <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
                                       </tag>
                                   </tags>
                               </tagClass>
                                </tagClasses>
                       </tagListOptions>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```
2. Define the non-aggregate report in the `<reporting>` section of the Parent POM `pom.xml`.

   ```
   <reporting>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${io.github.florianwolters.version.taglist-maven-plugin}</version>
               <reportSets>
                   <reportSet>
                   <id>taglist-report</id>
                   <inherited>true</inherited>
                   <reports>
                       <report>taglist</report>
                   </reports>
                   <configuration>
                       <aggregate>false</aggregate>
                   </configuration>
                   </reportSet>
               </reportSets>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </reporting>
   ```
3. Define the aggregate report in the `<reporting>` section of the Aggregator POM (that inherits the Parent POM) `pom.xml`.

   ```
   <reporting>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <reportSets>
                  <reportSet>
                       <id>aggregate-taglist-report</id>
                       <inherited>false</inherited>
                       <configuration>
                           <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                       </configuration>
                       <reports>
                           <report>taglist</report>
                       </reports>
                   </reportSet>
               </reportSets>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </reporting>
   ```